# updating variable between functions in c++

Tags: c++

My main program is to generate a random number to create movement of a object in a 2 dimensional array and to keep track of it.

one of my function `void current_row(int row){position = row};` keeps track of the current row of the object.

since the variable is not global. i am finding problems calling the current location and updating it to the next movement. this is how the other function may look like:

```
void movement (){
    int row;
    row = current_row();
    /*
     * Here is the problem i'm having. This may well be 
     * a third function which has the same information 
     * as my first function. But still how do I access
     * once without modifying it and access it  
     * again to update it?
     */

    // call another function that creates new row.
    // update that info to the row
}
```

i am new to c++.

Comment: This sounds more as a C problem, not C++.

Comment: @Martin: granted, and retagged.

Comment: This is both applicable in `C` and in `C++`. But if the OP explicitely says `C++`, why retag it as `C`? That's just wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Use an instance variable to keep track of it. That's why instance variables exist: To hold their values between function calls.

Answer (score 0):

In case it's an OOP environment (as C++ tag implies), some class should declare **int row** as a class member (including a getter and a setter as methods).

Another option is declaring the variable at the head of the **main()** part of the program and call functions with row as a function parameter.

void movement(int row)
{

}

You can consider the parameter be passed by reference if you are intending to change it, otherwise it would be better declaring it const inside the function parameter declaration. If part of the answer sounds unfamiliar to you I would suggest reading through :
[What's the difference between passing by reference vs. passing by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373419/whats-the-difference-between-passing-by-reference-vs-passing-by-value)

Comment: ah thanx. i was so focused on formatting it from function to function i forgot i could put it in main. i will work on it and see if it gets solved. and yes i would rather not get into creating classes. (we are studying that topic atm).

Comment: @firelitte Glad to help, post back if you get stuck. Also you should accept one of the answers if the issue is resolved.